# Sci fi movie about a time traveling city

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

It is an old cheap sci fi movie that got forgotten. It was about a war in the future with cyborgs. The last standing city of humanity's survivors plan to use the city energy source to travel back through time to escape demise. But their first jump is in our time near a small desert town and they open a small hole to send some of their warriors to check and secure the site for the town's arrival. Some cyborgs also follow them to attempt to sabotage the whole thing. When the town people start dying they join forces with the people of the future to fight them off. At the end the battle is decided when the main hero points the energy beam of the city against the hordes of cyborgs and wins the war.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The Time Guardian" (Australian; 1987)

Here is the plot summary from Wikipedia:

In the year 4039, a city of survivors from the Neutron Wars travels through time and space escaping the Jen-Diki, a race of cyborgs intent on wiping out humanity. Two soldiers from the city, Ballard and Petra, are transported to the South Australian outback in 1988 to prepare a landing site for the city. Petra is wounded and Ballard seeks help from geologist Annie Lassite. An advance party of Jen-Diki arrive in Australia.

Below is the trailer from YouTube. You can see the cyborgs fighting the humans at the beginning.

Comment: Very terminator like.

Comment: In case people are interested, it also features Carrie Fisher. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dB6vBTQX03g).

Comment: Oh, yeah! that is the one. Its really a shame that a movie is being ignored like that just because it is Australian. Google searches shows you the same well known movies over and over. I even saw this site where they put the most pompous head line ever: "Every time travel movie ever made!" I mean really??? And you know that movie wasn't there plus a few more. Thank you "the guest"? Is that your nickname?